# lidR: Save LAS files from a clip_roi list

Tags: r, clip, lidar, lidr, point-cloud

I have clipped a point cloud with a shapefile containing multiple polygons, using `clip_roi()` function. The result is a list of LAS files. However, when I try to loop through the list and save each individual file, I get `Error: Argument is not a LAS object`. Here is the code:

```
las = readLAS("plot_a3.las", filter = "-drop_z_below 0")
polys = shapefile("plot_a_segments.shp")
clipped = clip_roi(las, polys)

for (i in range(lengths(clipped))) 
{
  file <-file.path('Plot_A', paste0('plot_a_', clipped[i], '.las'))
  writeLAS(clipped[i], file, index = FALSE)
}
```

How do I correctly save the output so that each clipped point cloud is saved as a separate LAS file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`clipped[i]` returns a `list` with one element. You meant `clipped[[i]]` with double brackets. Also `clipped[i]` within `paste0()` is meaningless.

Actually your use case is already covered by the package. Assuming that your shapefile has an attribute `PLOTID` (replace with something else if needed)

```r
ctg <- readLAScatalog("folder/plot_a3.las", filter = "-drop_z_below 0")
polys <- shapefile("folder/plot_a_segments.shp")

opt_output_files(ctg) <- "folder/plot_a_{PLOTID}"
new_ctg <- clip_roi(ctg, polys)
```

If you don't have any unique ID in the shapefile you can generate other filename patterns with `{XCENTER}`, `{YCENTER}`, `{ID}` and so on. See the documentation