# R lidR save clip_roi object to a LAS file

Tags: r, lidr

I am trying to save a `clip_roi` object to a LAS file and I used the code in the following question. However I still get the same error:

```
Error: Argument is not a LAS object
```

How can I save a `clip_roi` object to a `LAS` file?

[lidR: Save LAS files from a clip_roi list](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/368983/lidr-save-las-files-from-a-clip-roi-list)

Code:

```
for (i in range(lengths(clip_roi_object))) 
{
  writeLAS(clip_roi_object[[i]], "path/filename.las", index = FALSE)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question your are linking contains several flaws. Copying the question was not the good idea, you should have copied the answer even if it is a little out-dated by the fact that we prefer to use `sf` nowadays. Something like that

```r
library(lidR)
library(sf)
ctg <- readLAScatalog(...)
polys <- st_read("shapefile.shp")
opt_output_files(ctg) <- "folder/plot_{ID}"
new_ctg <- clip_roi(ctg, polys)
```